# How can I access the "fades" dropdown option in Ableton?

Tags: daw, ableton-live, production, audio-editing

I'm having trouble finding the fades option circled in red in the following screenshot, which was taken from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=287oH1PILWQ) video:

[image: youtuber - once fade option is selected]

Here's a closer look at his options:

[image: youtuber - fade option in dropdown]

And here's what I'm seeing in arrangement view (first image below is in automation mode and second image below is not in automation mode):

[image: no fade option in dropdown automation mode]

[image: no fade option (but fade handles) not in automation mode]

I have searched the internet, including Ableton's reference manual, but I am still not sure what the solution is.  Any tips?

Thank you!

9/19 update:  I've contacted Ableton Support on this--let's see if they can help.

Comment: It's a commercial product you have to pay money for. Have you asked the seller for support? How did they respond?

Comment: Ableton support is not good.  I'm still waiting on a response for an inquiry I made a week ago (separate issue).  Also, you pay up front for the product--I don't continue to pay for support or anything like that.

Comment: Try pressing the "a" key (you may need to select the track first — try both ways). If that works, let me know, and I'll type up a more complete answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a basic customer support question, best addressed to the application developer.

Comment: @aaron I used the A key in order to turn automation mode on/off.  I also turned the MIDI icon on and off to see if that would help.  I used this video as a reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fL7wF08WoV8

Comment: Okay, I found that same video — plus a few other references to the same thing — so clearly that's not the issue. There were also some chat-forum discussions indicating this is a long-standing bug, but I didn't find anything about a workaround.